# Unable to Sign In to iTunes Connect: "Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect"

Tags: app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I am a member of my company's development team, with the role of Admin. I can access the Member Center of the team at https://developer.apple.com/

However, when I I attempt to sign in at https://itunesconnect.apple.com I am presented with the following error message:

[image: Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect]

[image: Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect]

> Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect. Learn More

I am an admin on the development team. When I visit `Developer > Member Center > People` I do not see any permissions related to iTunes Connect.

How do I gain access to my team's iTunes Connect portal?

Comment: Be aware to another option: you're trying to login with *Enterprise* account, and Enterprise accounts can't login to iTunes Connect.

Comment: Apple told me to log into itunes connect, but it turned out to be appstoreconnect.apple.com for me. Hope that helps someone else in 2022+.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is not enough to be a member of the Apple Developer Account / Member Center team.

The account must **also** be added as an iTunes Connect User.

From an **existing iTunes Connect admin account**, add the new user to iTunes Connect:

`iTunes Connect > Users and Roles > "+" > Add iTunes Connect User`

[image: Users and Roles]

Comment: but how do I go to `iTunes Connect > Users and Roles >` if I cannot with my main Apple Developer ID?

Comment: You need to find the admin for the iTunes Connect service and get them to add you (possibly as another admin).

Answer (score 41):

The solution is simple: Login with this account to iTunes (not iTunesConnect). I am sure you didn't do that. You can take your iPhone or iPad to do that or download the iTunes application.

Comment: This did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: OMG, yes this is correct solution. goggelj explanation is concise and clear, but his solution to login into appleid etc is not working. This is what's working. My working "Apple ID" is a different Apple ID than what I usually use on my phone, so my working Apple ID is never signed up into iTunes. Thanks!

Comment: This also worked for me. My "everyday" Apple ID is my personal email, but I signed up for the developer programme with a work email. That work email had never logged into itunes. Once it had, everything worked. Thanks Ton!

Comment: That didn't for me. Does the account have to be part of developer account/program + logged into iTunes before? I only did the latter but fail to login to iTunes Connect.

Comment: You need the account to be part of the developer program else it wouldn't work at all. iTunesconnect is only accessible for developer accounts. So if you sign up with the account as a developer, I guess your problem will be solved.

Comment: I would hesitate to call this a simple solution. Hardly intuitive is it?

Answer (score 6):

If your Apple Id is added to your team account recently, you need to activate it first by clicking on the link that Apple sent to you with the activation code. 
After that, you should be able to login to iTunes connect. 
 
P/S: You may need to check your internet connection, firewall, proxy setting to make sure you can connect to itunes connect server. This happened to me as I used my company network to login. After switched to my 3G hotspot, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue. The error message gives no clue that, as an app developer, I could no longer login to iTunes. The fix for me was to now go to another website: https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issues and I got quite a few random answers from iTunesConnect support until I managed to get an iTunes Connect supervisor.

Here is what is happening:

1. Your team iTunes Connect guy added you with an email address
2. The aim is for that email address to be the iTunes Connect email and id
3. You have never been created as an iTunesConnect user with this email
4. When this email/id was added (someone filled the name and email in iTunesConnect) clicked 'Next', iTunes would have 'initialised' the account

This '`initialise`' is key:

Apple DOES NOT know the user but they have enough details to set a **skeleton** account allowing the user to login.

To turn this into a real/complete account, the user has to **log in** to [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com), add **birth date** AND **answer/set** the security questions.

Once that is done, the account will become a fully fledged account.

Then, if you send an invite (and if they user did not give up and switched to Android), when he/she accepts/clicks on the invitation, they will be set up as expected.

Good luck!

p.s.
I'm the iTunesConnect guy in my company...

Comment: I am a single account enrolled in the Apple Developer Program. I have a birth date and security questions set, but I still get "Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect." when I try to log into iTunes connect. Trying to follow their "sign up" process for apps on iTunes connect just sends me to the Apple Developer Program enrollment page.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for me was a variation on the one given by @zevij. Just log into this site using the id/pw:

http://appleid.apple.com/

Then visit itunesconnect.apple.com.

I have no idea why this works and it seems like something is seriously wrong at the mothership when it comes to Web. But there you go.

Answer (score 1):

I received an email from Apple on Feb 12, 2019 that seems to indicate that there is now a single permission that gives access to the Apple Developer website *and* App Store Connect:

> #### Teams and roles have been unified.
>
> Dear PERSON,
>
> Developer teams and roles are now simpler. Organizations enrolled in the Apple Developer Program now have one team and one set of roles that provide access to the Apple Developer website and App Store Connect. You can view your current role by signing in to App Store Connect. Changes to roles can be made by Account Holders and Admins in the Users and Access section.
>
> If you have any questions, contact us.
>
> Best regards,
> Apple Developer Relations

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's still facing this issue. The above solutions did not work for me at this point in time. This is what I've done to get it working (from apple's help):

**How to generate an app-specific password**

- Sign in to your Apple ID account page.
- In the Security section, click Generate Password below App-Specific Passwords.
- Follow the steps on your screen. After you generate your app-specific password, enter or paste it into the password field of the app as you would normally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this on the **recent MacOS version/machine**, Here's what worked for me.

- Open music app on you Macbook
- From the sidebar visit the "Itunes store"
- Navigate to "Account", for me I found it in the bottom right quarter of the **Itunes store homepage**.
- Click on "Account" and it should prompt to sign in, sign in and fill up the payment method in next screen(can set to none if you don't wish to add any, but still need to fill address and stuff)
- After doing this, I was able to sign in to App store in without an issue.