# Enable Apple ID for iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, apple-id

So I have an Apple ID that was under a company's iTunes Connect, so when I got myself into the Apple Dev Program individually for the same Apple ID, I was not able to enter iTunes Connect associated with my Apple ID. The company removed me from iTunes Connect, and now the Apple ID is not associated with any iTunes Connect. How can I enable my Apple ID for iTunes Connect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Sign In to iTunes Connect: "Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867975/unable-to-sign-in-to-itunes-connect-your-apple-id-isnt-enabled-for-itunes-con)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your account is now not able to access the iTunesConnect Program so you need to link your account to any paid Apple ID to access their iTunesConnect Programs and see the Apps or you need to pay for your Apple ID.