# your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am a member of my company's development team, with the role of Admin. I can access the Member Center of the team at https://developer.apple.com/

However, when I I attempt to sign in at https://itunesconnect.apple.com I am presented with the following error message:

> Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect.

Comment: What was the error message you encountered..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to Sign In to iTunes Connect: "Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867975/unable-to-sign-in-to-itunes-connect-your-apple-id-isnt-enabled-for-itunes-con)

Answer (score 3):

iTunesConnect users are different from development team. You need to ask you iTunesConnect agent or admin to invite you to iTunesConnect.

Just login to iTunesConnect -> User and Roles > iTunes Connect Users and add new user. And same appleid can be used for both.

[image]

Comment: But how can i go in user & roles section until i'm getting this error. This is not letting me login in.